# An easy question (given as an image) of showing $\ker θ = \langle X^2-1\rangle$ where $ θ : ℝ[X] \to M_2(ℝ)$ is a homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-homomorphism, polynomial-rings

[image]

Is my solution correct?

Let $f(X)\in ℝ[X]$. Then $f(X)= (X^2-1)q(X) + r + sX$ $(*)$ for some $q(X), (r + sX)\in ℝ[X]$ by the division theorem for polynomials.

So $$θ(f(X)) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
r&s\\
s&r\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So now suppose $f(X)\in \ker θ$ which means $θ(f(X))=0$ which means $r,s = 0$. From $(*)$ this means $f(X) = (X^2-1)q(X)\in \langle X^2-1\rangle$. Therefore, $\ker θ ⊆ \langle X^2-1\rangle$.

Now suppose $f(X)\in \langle X^2-1\rangle$ which means $f(X) = (X^2-1)q(X)$ for some $q(X)\in ℝ[X]$. Thus $$θ(f(X)) =
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0\\
0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So $f(X)\in \ker θ$ which means $\langle X^2-1\rangle ⊆ \ker θ$. Hence, $\ker θ = \langle X^2-1\rangle$.

Comment: Please use \langle and \rangle instead of plain < and >. Use \to instead that of -->

Comment: `\in` creates $\in$

Comment: If this is for a homework I would probably write an extra line to justify your formula for $\theta(f(X))$, but otherwise it looks good.

Comment: @CaptainLama Thanks for your help :) Could you also aide me in this question please: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3415431/a-question-given-as-an-image-on-how-to-show-a-polynomial-ring-is-equal-to-a-pr